# Python Libraries

Tags: python, pip, easy-install

I'm in desperate need of a cross platform framework as I have vast numbers of .NET products that I'm trying to port to Linux. I have started to work with Python/pyQt and the standard library and all was going well until I try to import non-standard libraries. I'm hearing about pip and easy_install and I'm completely confused about this.

My products need to ship with everything required to execute them, so in the .NET world I simply package my DLLs (or licensed DLLs) with my product.

As a test bed I'm trying to import this library called requests: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests

I've got an `__init__.py` file and the library source in my program directory but it isn't working. Please tell me that there is a simple way to include libraries without needing any kind of extra package installer.

Comment: change `init.py` to `__init__.py`.

Comment: yes, it is `__init__.py`. I need to know that I can include 3rd party libraries in the same directory as my code and it will work without the need of some 3rd party package downloader

Comment: Re: "Please tell me that there is a simple way to include libraries without needing any kind of extra package installer.": It's common to include a `setup.py` file that describes the installation, pulling in all required packages. Does that count? Here is the `setup.py` for `requests`: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/setup.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you start by familiarizing yourself with python packages (see [the distutils docs](http://docs.python.org/3/distutils/introduction.html).  Pip is simply a manager that install packages directly from the internet repository, so that you don't need to manually go and download them.  So for, example, as stated under "Installing" on the `requests` homepage, you simply run `pip install requests` in a terminal, without manually downloading anything.

Packaging your product is a different story, and the way you do it depends on the target system.  On windows, the easiest might be to create an installer using [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) which will install all dependencies.  You might also want to use [cx-freeze](http://cx_freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to pull all the dependencies (including the python interpreter) into a single package.

On linux, many of the dependencies will already be including in most distributions. so you should just list them as requirements when creating your package (e.g. `deb` for ubuntu).  Other dependencies might not be included in the distro's repo, but you can still list them as requirements in `setup.py`.

I can't really comment on Mac, since I've never used python on one, but I think that it would be similar to the linux approach.

Comment: Packaging isn't a problem, I prefer WiX over NSIS due to it's tight .NET integration so no issues there. It sounds like you're saying that I can indeed package and deliver other libraries in Python and users are not required to use a packaging engine to obtain these dependencies. That's enough for me to continue investigating Python as a viable alternative. Thanks!